# str_replace убрать из строк

Tags: php

Нужно отпарсить приходящие строки от оборудования. значения должны получатся так 542 225 105

```
    $tuarray=array('Timeticks: (455215351) 542 days, 16:29:13.51','INTEGER: 225','STRING: 105');
foreach ($tuarray as $key => $value) {
$value=str_replace("INTEGER:","", $value);
$value=str_replace("STRING:","", $value);

$start = strpos($value, ")") + 1;

$end = strpos($value, "days");
//echo $end;
$length = $end - $start;

$result = trim(substr($value, $start, $length));
echo '<pre>'.$key.'--   ';
echo $result;   
}
```

а получается так 
0--   542
1--   22
2--   10

Comment: И зачем делать `substr` если в строке нет ни "days" ни скобок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tuarray=array('Timeticks: (455215351) 542 days, 16:29:13.51','INTEGER: 225','STRING: 105');

$tuarray=array_map( function($v){ return explode(': ',$v)[1]; }, $tuarray);
preg_match('/( [0-9]{1,} )/si', $tuarray[0], $days); 
$tuarray[0]=$days[1];

# Результат
echo implode('<br>', $tuarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае проще воспользоваться регулярным выражением.
Можно заметить, что во всех трех строках искомое число идет после пробела. Это позволяет использовать простую регулярку,

```
~ (\d+)~
```

Шаблон в скобках попадёт в `$matches` и дальше останется только оттуда его достать

```
$new = [];
foreach ($tuarray as $row) {
    preg_match('~ (\d+)~', $row, $matches);
    $new[] = $matches[1];
}
var_export($new);
```